# jQuery show animation is not working properly

Tags: jquery

Standalone code:

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup',"#billing_email",function(){
 var val = jQuery(this).val();
 if(val.length == < 4)
 {
      jQuery("#order_review").hide();
 }
 else
 {
      jQuery("#order_review").show();
 }
```

works fine, it shows the element after the requirment was met, but when I try to add animation to the .show with "slow" it stops working.

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup',"#billing_email",function(){
     var val = jQuery(this).val();
     if(val.length == < 4)
     {
          jQuery("#order_review").hide();
     }
     else
     {
          jQuery("#order_review").show("slow", function() );
     }

 });
```

I looked it up on https://api.jquery.com/show/ and I just cant get it working, could you please help me?

thanks

Comment: Your anonymous function has no body. It should be `function() { ... }` - notice yours is missing the `{ .. }`. If you don't need anything to happen when the animation completes, you don't need to include the callback argument at all; just do `jQuery("#order_review").show("slow")`.

Comment: Shouldn't `val.length == < 4` just be `val.length <= 4`?

Comment: ^ That'd be another one. @JaroslavMelich, I'd suggest doing some research about debugging in JS. Any sort of troubleshooting (or even just an IDE) should've made these errors quite clear.

Comment: @Taplar for the `val.length == < 4 ` was a copying error I already corrected that for `val.lenght < 4 ` which works fine.

@TylerRoper thanks for the answer, you were right, now it works just fine,appreciated